# Tooltip text truncated

Tags: windows, winapi, wtl

I found out that sometimes, the text on my tooltip is not fully displayed. Here's an example for such text:

> WWWWW WWWW, WW WWWWWWWW
>
> WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWW

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

My tooltip creation code (WTL):

```
CToolTipCtrl tooltip;
TOOLINFO toolInfo;

tooltip.Create(window, NULL, NULL, TTS_NOFADE);

toolInfo = CToolInfo(TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_TRACK | TTF_ABSOLUTE, 
    tooltip, 0, NULL, L"WWW...");

tooltip.AddTool(&toolInfo);

tooltip.SendMessage(TTM_SETTITLE, (WPARAM)hIcon, (LPARAM)L"Title");
```

Is it a known issue? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what mean `sometimes` ? the *same* text (length) can be sometime fully displayed and sometime not ? or begin from some concrete length it begin truncated ?

Comment: @RbMm By sometimes I mean - with some texts. The behavior is consistent, i.e. the same text is either truncated or not.

Comment: passing `tooltip` into ctor of `CToolInfo` seems to be a typo - a real control's HWND should passed instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like calling `tooltip.SetMaxTipWidth(MAXINT);` fixes it.

Non-WTL version: `SendMessage(..., TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH, 0, MAXINT);`